# How to find MYSQL Logs for Drop Delete Record?

Tags: mysql

I am using SQlyog Ultimate for Mysql GUI. I want to know who is deleting, Dropping table and record. I want to track the User Ip and Name.

If there is any method to track please share with me.

I found some Link but not able to understand
[How to show the last queries executed on MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650238/how-to-show-the-last-queries-executed-on-mysql)

Thanks
Sitansu

Answer (score 1):

You must enable query logging on server as described on the official page:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-logs.html

Here general logging is the easiest approach that can be used to resolve your objective. Link shared by you shows two different methods of achieving the same. You can **use following queries as root user** to get what you want

```
SET GLOBAL log_output = 'TABLE';
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';    

select event_time,user_host,argument
from mysql.general_log
where command_type='Query' and 
upper(argument) rlike '(DROP|DELETE|TRUNCATE)+';
```

Beware that it will fill server disk space very faster.

Answer (score 0):

SQlyog Ultimate for Mysql GUI - is good tool, but haven't any relations with Your question.

With MySQL You are restricted with not a big list of options:

- You can enable general log, but in this case You can easy kill server performance, because server would log everything (absolutely) and also size of logs would be grow dramatically on a busy server
- You can use MariaDB audit plugin, it excellent, but it part of subscription edition (and it not cheap). I not fully understand license policy of MariaDB, but You could request direct, they answer good.
- You can switch to MySQL Enterprise it also contain audit plugin
- You can test McAfee audit plugin (https://github.com/mcafee/mysql-audit)